# CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS sends data with strange encoding?

Tags: c++, libcurl

This is what I get http://requestb.in/1kduz591?inspect

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://requestb.in/1kduz591");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://requestb.in/1kduz591");
string data="abc";

curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,data);
```

Comment: `curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data.c_str() );`

Comment: Yup thats it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html) sends the data *exactly* as you pass to it, it doesn't translate, transcode or encode anything of it.

libcurl is a C API so you **MUST** provide the data as a plain `char *` and not a `string`. Use [string].c_str() or similar if you insist on using C++.